# asp.net MVC 3.0 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net MVC(3.0) application, I've a page ManageOverTime.cshtml, but when I run my application and navigate to that page, it show page not found error.

my routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "HRMgmt.Controllers" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: You don't navigate to a `cshtml` file. You navigate to an action method in a controller that returns that view.

Comment: I am no expert but my understanding is that you make a call to an action in a  controller and the controller returns the page  in "return View("ManageOverTime.cshtml",null)", no?

Comment: it's useless you show your (rather default) route config - you should show the Controller (yes you need a *controller* MyXController with an action `ManageOverTime` to show this *view* on the url `.../MyX/ManageOverTime` - and yes you can overwrite the name of the view there so it does not have to be `.../ManageOverTime`)

Comment: Yes, View name was not same as the action name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a controller by right button clicking on Controllers folder in VS. Let's say the name is `MyController`. Copy the cshtml page either in the views folder that VS must have created for this controller or in shared folder.
2. In the controller, add a method, let's say the name is `MyMethod`
3. In the method do whatever processing you need to do and then return the cshtml page, something like this

   return View ("ManageOvertime.cshtml", nothing);
4. Deploy your app. Then in the browser, visit  `<yourwebsite>/MyController/MyMethod`